# Special keys such as Enter and Ctrl+key combinations don't work with gVim

Tags: key-bindings, gvim

On a new Linux system (RedHat7), gvim has strange behavior. Pressing `Enter` gives me `~M`, pressing `Esc` gives me `~[`, `C-V` gives me `~V`. Curiously, `Enter` on the numpad works. I tried mapping the `~M` (which is 0x8d) in `Enter`, without success. What is wrong with my configuration?

To complete the information, it was a package added by my computer engineer. There are also another vim on `/usr/bin/vim` (without graphic interface) working normally.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your issue is probably related to encoding settings. But you should edit your question, because it is not clear which keys you are pressing (I guess you had problems with the markdown engine of vi.stackexchange). Also it is unclear if you are using Vim with a graphical interface (gVim) or Vim on the terminal (there is no such thing as gvim terminal).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "gvim terminal"?

Comment: I mean by "terminal": the key pressed, when I edit a file under gvim,  isn't correctly mapped to the right one. Like I said, pressing "enter" doesn't send a carriage return but a character 0x8d